# Use Dagger2 Android Injection Support without specifying the class name

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Is there a way in Dagger2 or in Dagger2 Android Injection support to inject the member instances without specifying the class names of the fragments.

I have a modular project where

The following line is asking to provide a binder Factory for the injectable class.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
      AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);
      super.onAttach(context);
    }
```

But my intention is to provide the injecting members through different modules in the project, where the I wouldn't need to specify the class name of the Fragment at all.

Is this possible in Dagger2 injection or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in Dagger2 or in Dagger2 Android Injection support to inject the member instances without specifying the class names of the fragments.

***tl;dr*** No. You always need a component that contains a `.inject(FragmentInQuestion fragment)` method for every Fragment you want to inject.

---

Dagger uses annotation processing at compile time to resolve all of your `.inject(SomeFragment fragment)` methods where it looks up fields annotated with `@Inject` and creates code to inject them.

It *needs* the actual class name, since it will only generate code for the class used with its fields.

```
class Fragment {
  // no @Inject annotated fields, part of framework!
}

class SomeFragment extens Fragment {
  @Inject SomeDependency dep;
}
class OtherFragment extens Fragment {
  @Inject OtherDependency dep;
}
```

Declaring one generic component that injects all your fragments is impossible.
`.inject(Fragment fragment)` would not inject *any* properties, since `Fragment` does not contain any `@Inject` annotated fields. So neither of the `dep` fields in the above sample would be provided and they both would be `null`.

You *could* create a `BaseFragment` that contains common objects and write an injection for it, but again, any annotated fields of its children would not be supplied.

You could try some other workarounds, but in the end it would always mean that you'd be injecting or be working with a base type. While this might be feasible in *some* situations, I don't think it would work on more than some special edge cases.

---

The Android Injection part of Dagger 2 takes this approach and creates a generic interface that your components have to implement along with a Builder to bind the type in question.

```
interface AndroidInjector<T> {
  inject(T instance)
}
```

By implementing this interface `AndroidInjection` can then look up (and create) the correct component and inject your Fragment. For the reasons mentioned above this will always be the actual class of your Fragment, and not some base type.

So by using the Android Injection part you won't be able to use some common base class, and even without it you'd have a hard time.

---

If you're looking for a way to move out the call of `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` to somewhere else you should look at the Google [Android Architecture Components sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/674b6be9f956b3579db60fb35329e25395c03649/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.java) project where they use `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` to inject the fragments globally at the right time.